# Windows Server 2019 users become read only

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

I have an issue with Windows Server 2019. I've just set up a server for development purposes and
once set up I created another "normal user" on it. The problem that arose then was that the new
"normal" user only seems to have read only access to everything except stuff under the user profile
(Documents etc).

What I do need a something in between, that is able to run programs, create and edit files that are not system files etc but not have a complete sysadmin permissions on the machine (much like you'd see in the our prod environment), is there a way to do this?

I know it works in Windows Server 2012 and 2016, but 2019 seems to have implemented something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the new "normal" user only seems to have read only access to everything except stuff under the user profile ...

As "Our Friends in Redmond" are often wont to say:

> This is By Design.

It's called [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) and is the way that Windows has *wanted* to work ever since Windows **XP** came out (which is when UAC first started to appear).

Running programs (from directories that appear in the PATH environment variable) should not be a problem.

Editing any files *outside* of the User's profile requires you to work *with* the Windows security system and to grant appropriate and relevant permission on the directories that you want the users to mess .. sorry .. work with.

Comment: Thanks. Then at least I know where to start. :)